# How to have specific layout for 6 inches xxhdpi and xxxhdpi devices

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have folders for xxhdpi and xxxhdpi and you know same density can have different screen sizes so I handled devices 5 inches devices by sw410dp but as soon as screen size reaches 6 inches(especially pixel devices - pixel 2 xl) the layout becomes messy, what sw or h should I try to support 6 inches devices

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a separate layout for each screen size, create one view with constraint layout. You can then align constraints as you like which will automatically resize the imageView, textView, or any view according to screen size.

Read this [quickstart guide](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) to build responsive UI with constraint layout.